# Share content between classic asp app and asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cookies, asp-classic

I have a classic asp app and a .net that need to live side by side.  They each are in different app pools.

The existing classic asp application uses cookie to validate a user has authenticated.  I want to avoid having to change anything on the classic asp side if i can.

My issue is with the cookie.  It seems, and I am not sure how since they are in different app pools, i can see the cookie until the .net app does a postback then i loose it.  It seems to have deleted as the classic app looses the cookie as well.  when that happens the checks that are in place route the user back to the login page to reauthenticate.

Options i can think of:

1. Ideal fix would be to be allow me to read/check the cookie and leave it as is for now.
2. If the above doesn't work can I use recreate the cookie do you think each time?
3. I don't know why postbacks are causing the cookie to get deleted but could i skip the check server side and locate the cookie via javascript or jquery perhaps?  If so how?

I would like to avoid having to write back to the database saying i authenticated unless that is all it comes down to.  Also, as i mentioned I want to try and avoid having to do much at all on the classic asp side as it will result in me hitting every single page.

how do i fix this cookie issue?

Thanks.

EDIT:  one other thing I should note is that when i look in fiddler (a tool which i not very savvy) i can see the cookie on the classic side.  when I load the .net page within fiddler it shows the cookie as empty however the first load the cookie contents is found in page_load.  I dont get it?  how i know this is within page_load i am looking for the cookie and filling a simple label with its contents.  Any time a postback occurs the contents is lost.

Comment: I think i may have fixed this.  Anyone tell me if this is a bad idea as I have not used cookies in my past.  each time there is a postback I can see the cookie in both request and response however the response value is always null.  I am simply checking for a value in request and if there is one updating the response's value from null to the value on the request.  This seems to work. any issues people see?

Comment: Seems when I publish to production though i cannot find the cookie again.  man this is frustrating.

Comment: Setting the response.cookie's value each time seemed to fix this for me for the time being.  I hope this helps someone else.